# HTTP Body Regex

Tags: regex, burp

I want to automate a process of sending HTTP request using the regex to remove any character or number located between the **=** and the **&** with burpsuite **( Autorize Extension )** 
[image]

The body:

```
id=169413&token=2y10l02e7J2mBD6lTnSv9uHSZD5QylM2JsM21Hyi4J&sub_profile_id=14317
```

i want something similar at

```
id=&token=&sub_profile=
```

I tried with `\=[A-Za-z1-9]+` but without results

it could be done in three steps example capture just id=Anything and remove 'Anything' then do it with the rest

Comment: Obligatory post about the [futility of trying to parse XHTML with a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/62576)

Comment: @KenWhite Yes but I will not do this process with HTTP itself I will rather analyze the request with burpsuite more closely with Autorize (Extension of burp) who will then modify the Header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
\=([^&]+)\&?
```